# Magento: Update block position with before/after attribute from local.xml layout reference

Tags: magento, layout, themes

I need to append the `before` attribute to a block via a layout update reference call.

This is my `local.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="content.footer" as="contentFooter" translate="label" after="-">
                <label>Content Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementId"><value>content-footer</value></action>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>clear</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs.container">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>category.title</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.title" template="catalog/category/title.phtml" before="content.footer"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

My problem is, on the `content` block I create a `content.footer` block that you can assign widgets to in admin. I use `after="-"` on the `content.footer` block so in my mind, should put it ALWAYS at the bottom of the content block but this is not the case.

When you view a catalog category and it inserts the `category.products` block in to the `content` block, it displays underneath the `content.footer` block. The only way to make it work is if I redefine it in my `local.xml` and include all the child blocks in `category.products`, and set before `before="content.footer"`.

So I thought why can't I use a reference to `category.products` in the `catalog_category_default` layout and set the block's `before` attribute, I tried the following:

```
<reference name="category.products">
    <action method="setBefore"><value>content.footer</value></action>
</reference>
```

Which had no affect.

I also noticed the `setAttribute()` function in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` which saw it's just a wrapper for `setData()` but thought I would try it anyway, still nothing:

```
<reference name="category.products">
    <action method="setAttribute"><key>before</key><value>content.footer</value></action>
</reference>
```

Is it possible to do what I want? Does before/after only apply to blocks in the same reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Layout updates are processed in order of layout update handles. Your block *is* being added last to content but only for the `default` LUH. Other handles (`catalog_product_view`, `catalog_category_layered`, etc) are processed after this handle.

If you truly need a content footer everywhere and want to make sure that it is the last thing inside of the **content** div, you should add your block to the **root** node in the `default handle` and customize the **root** templates (directly under `page/`, e.g. `page/1column.phtml`) by adding a `getChildHtml('your.block')` call after the `getChildHtml('content')` call. This will ensure that your block is always immediately at the end of the content blocks.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I thought this may be the case. Seeing as I only _really_ need it in the catalog category pages I will remove it from the default layout and update the category layouts when I do my other updates so I can force it to the bottom.